# ElasticSearch daily aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

We store in ElasticSearch logs in the next (simplified) format:

```
     Timestamp      | ResourceID  | UserID | Traffic
=================================================
2017-08-17T12-12-02 |     R1      | U1     | 10
2017-08-17T12-13-52 |     R1      | U1     | 20
2017-08-17T12-12-55 |     R2      | U2     | 30
2017-08-17T12-13-49 |     R2      | U2     | 40
```

It takes a lot of space and we want to store aggregated data into separate index. Later we will delete raw logs and will use only aggregated data.

We want to get the next:

```
   Date    | ResourceID  | UserID | Traffic
============================================
2017-08-17 |     R1      |   U1   | 30
2017-08-17 |     R2      |   U2   | 70
```

What we came so far:

1. Use `scroll` request to ES, than we have to write code to aggregate every record and to store results. It leads to high internal traffic and possible `OutOfMemoryError`.
2. Optimize solution #1: Request a least of unique `ResourceID`s (terms with partitioning?), and use `scroll` with filter by `ResourceID`. Is it possible to get the whole list of unique `ResourceID`s from ES?
3. Use ES `aggs` requests. ES returns only fields in aggregation, so we loose some required columns.
4. Use Standalone Spark installation for aggregating. But it has the same problems as approach #1.

What are recommended solutions and best practices?

Comment: if a scroll search leads you to OOM, something else is going on.  That should not happen. can you share that stack trace?

Comment: This is imaginary situation, not real. I meant that there can be a lot of data, that can't fit into memory.

Comment: then slicing the scroll search based on some app criteria makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with using elasticsearch-hadoop (only spark) binding. It loads every document from ES index.